# Uploading File from Client to Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, file-upload

I am working on ajax-page using PageMethods (web service) to interact with server.
I want to allow a user to upload a given file to server (at some fixed path on server).

I know about FileUpload control in asp.net, but that wont work in my case. Since i dont want to user UpdatePanel or a dedicated server page.

Is there a way to do it using client side ajax?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is that you have edited here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using embeded flash, Google uses it in Gmail. 
Here is a [good one](http://www.inaflashuploader.com/), it is free and you can use with asp.net as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an Ajax-way, but you could add an iframe to your page, and load a dedicated upload-page in that inside it.

On the upload page you can then use the [FileUpload control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).